# C# - How to add code INTO background threads before starting them?

Tags: c#, multithreading, lambda, threadpool

I want to write a helper function `start` that starts pool threads for me but also adds some code before the actual background processing starts **in the very same pool thread**. So the background thread must do some extra work. I would call `start` very often and the extra code might change. So I wanted create a kinda factory for pool threads.

Would that be even possible ? If yes, how would I "inject" code into threads ?

I tried this:

```
class Program
{
    private static void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello world");
    }

    private static void start1(Action param1)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                // extra work is here
                param1.Invoke(); // starts another subthread ?
            });
    }

    private static void start2(WaitCallback param1)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(param1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        start1(new Action(test));
        start2(o => { test(); });

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            ExtraWork();
            param1.Invoke();
        });
```

is equivalent to

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            ExtraWork();
            param1();
        });
```

Invoking a delegate does not start a new thread. (Why do you think it might?) So this code works just fine as it is. It will invoke the two functions sequentially.

Comment: When I call Invoke() I always think of controls that can't be manipulated by other threads. So they require invokes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add random. net code to run by string value. Unless you play with compiler and take the code, compile it into a DLL then call it with reflection i don't see how it can be done. If that's what you need i am scared to ask how the hell you need to do that.

If you do not require to have random code but specific functions well it's your lucky day. Functions can be pass as parameters. you can also build a list of function to get called in order and do it. That you will need to do more search on that, i haven't done this in years. Or maybe fellow stacker can comment and add link to nice article.

If the code need to be randomly generated and is not forced to be .net, example listing file in directory, opening program. Well you can look into scripting language. Worst case you can build a .vbs (Visual Basic Script) dynamically and run it. Then wait for it to create a text file for the results and read it to know what happened.

Comment: No, not code as strings. I just want to add some more calls for the background thread to execute.

Comment: collection of actions then